# Convert first page to tif using Magick.NET

Tags: c#, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick, magick.net

Following gm convert command converts **first page** of source.pdf to output.tif

```
convert source.pdf[0] output.tif
```

I wonder how to do it with Magick.NET library? Following code does not work for me.

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("source.pdf"))
{
  image.Write("output.tif");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick cannot handle PostScript and PDF files itself and by its own, 
for this it uses a third party software called Ghostscript.

So, you need to install the latest version of [GhostScript](https://ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) before you can convert a pdf using Magick.NET.

After installing GhostScript use following code to extract first page to TIF-file.

```
        using (MagickImageCollection image = new MagickImageCollection())
        {
            MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
            settings.Density = new Density(300, 300); // Settings the density to 300 dpi will create an image with a better quality
            settings.FrameIndex = 0; // First page
            settings.FrameCount = 1; // Number of pages
            image.Read(@"source.pdf", settings);
            image.Write(@"output.tif");
        }
```

You can adjust quality of resulting TIF by changing `settings.Density` param (300 dpi is for high quality offset/digital printing, 72 dpi is ok for monitor screens only).

Answer (score 0):

I am not a ImageMagick Magick.NET expert, but have you tried simply add [0] to your command as

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("source.pdf[0]"))
{
  image.Write("output.tif");
}
```

ImageMagick does require Ghostscript to be installed to read PDF files As was mentioned previously.